# Printing an error message if a user does not input a certain word

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, loops, error-messaging

This is kinda of a copy of a question I asked before, but kind of different.

I am a programming beginner (never programmed before) and I have been given a task (for school) to make a program that asks the user for a shape(s), then calculate that shape's volume from the dimensions given by the user. however if the user does not type in "quit", the program should keep asking the user for shapes and keep on calculating the volumes, and when the user do type in "quit", the program is suppose to print out the list of volumes calculated. the three shapes are Cube, pyramid and ellipsoid.

for example, if the user types in cube, cube, pyramid, pyramid, ellipsoid and then quit (along with the necessary dimensions to calculate volume), then the program should print out:

cube volumes: 4, 5

pyramid volumes: 6, 7

ellipsoid volumes: 8

NOTE: these numbers are just for example.

I have succeeded (kinda) in getting the program to notice errors and for the program to repeatedly ask the user for shapes and calculate volumes until "quit" has been entered. However, if the user does not enter cube for example, then the final output should be:

cube volumes: You have not done any calculations for the cube

pyramid volumes: 6, 7

ellipsoid volumes: 8

instead of what I am getting right now, which is:

cube volumes: []

pyramid volumes: 6, 7

ellipsoid volumes: 8

Is there any way to achieve the correct final output?

This is my code (it's probably not that great, but it's the best I can do right now as a beginner and with the stuff we are taught so far):

```
#A program that allows the user to continuously pick different shapes and calculate their volumes.

#import all functions from the math module.

import math
#allows the user to input the shape they want to calculate the volume of. Then that input is converted to all upper case
#letters so that no matter what the user enters, it will be recognizable by the program.
shape = input("please enter the shapes you want to calculate the volume of from cube, pyramid and ellipsoid, or Quit: ").upper()

#Initializing the lists for the volumes of the three different shapes as empty lists so that it can be filled
#later on.
VolumeListCube = []
VolumeListPyramid =[]
VolumeListEllipsoid = []

#defining the function that will calculate the volume of the cube and then adding them to the empty list VolumeListCube.
def VolumeCube (sideLength):
    volume = sideLength**3
    #Adding the values to the list
    VolumeListCube.append(volume)
    #Sorting the values in the created list in ascending order
    VolumeListCube.sort()
    return;

#defining the function that will calculate the volume of the pyramid and then adding them to the empty list VolumeListPyramid.
def VolumePyramid (baseLength, height):
    volume = round((1/3)*(baseLength**2)*height,1)
    #Adding the values to the list
    VolumeListPyramid.append(volume)
    #Sorting the values in the created list in ascending order
    VolumeListPyramid.sort()
    return;

#defining the function that will calculate the volume of the ellipsoid and then adding them to the empty list VolumeListEllipsoid.
def VolumeEllipsoid (radius1, radius2, radius3):
    volume = round((4/3)*math.pi*radius1*radius2*radius3,1)
    #Adding the values to the list
    VolumeListEllipsoid.append(volume)
    #Sorting the values in the created list in ascending order
    VolumeListEllipsoid.sort()
    return;

#The first while loop here checks if the user immediately inputs "Quit" or not, if they don't, then the next while loop is
#executed, if they do input "Quit", then the program will print the require message.
while shape != "QUIT":
    #This is a infinte while loop since true is always true, this allows the error message at the end to be displayed
    #and then loop back to the beginning of this loop, so that it can be executed again.
    while True:
        if shape in ["CUBE","PYRAMID","ELLIPSOID","QUIT"]:
            #These if functions will allow the user to input shape parameters depending on what shape the user has chosen, then
            #afterwards, another prompt is show for the user to choose another shape and input that shape's parameters. This will
            #continue until the user inputs "Quit", then the required message will be printed and the volume results fot all the
            #shapes chosen will be displayed in ascending order.
            if shape == "CUBE":
                sideLength = int(input("Please enter the length of the sides of the cube:"))
                #recalling the function that calculates the volume of the cube.
                VolumeCube (sideLength)
                #lets the user to input another shape they want to calculate the volume of.
                shape = input("please enter the shapes you want to calculate the volume of from cube, pyramid and ellipsoid, or Quit: ").upper()
            elif shape == "PYRAMID":
                baseLength = int(input("Please enter the base length:"))
                height = int(input("Please enter the height:"))
                # recalling the function that calculates the volume of the pyramid.
                VolumePyramid (baseLength, height)
                #lets the user to input another shape they want to calculate the volume of.
                shape = input("please enter the shapes you want to calculate the volume of from cube, pyramid and ellipsoid, or Quit: ").upper()
            elif shape == "ELLIPSOID":
                radius1 = int(input("Please enter the first radius:"))
                radius2 = int(input("Please enter the second radius:"))
                radius3 = int(input("Please enter the third radius:"))
                # recalling the function that calculates the volume of the ellipsoid.
                VolumeEllipsoid (radius1, radius2, radius3)
                #lets the user to input another shape they want to calculate the volume of.
                shape = input("please enter the shapes you want to calculate the volume of from cube, pyramid and ellipsoid, or Quit: ").upper()
            elif shape == "QUIT":
                print ("\nYou have come to the end of the session.\nthe volume calculated for each shape are shown below:\n")
                print("The volume of the cube(s) is:", VolumeListCube)
                print("The volume of the pyramid(s) is:", VolumeListPyramid)
                print("The volume of the ellipsoid(s) is:", VolumeListEllipsoid)
                #This exits the program to stop repeated prints that would be caused due to the while loop
                exit()
        else:
            print("Error, please enter a valid shape")
            shape = input("please enter the shapes you want to calculate the volume of from cube, pyramid and ellipsoid, or Quit: ").upper()

else:
    print ("\nYou have come to the end of the session.\nYou have not performed any volume calculations")
```

Comment: Part of programming is being able to break the main task down into smaller chunks that can be tackled and completed on their own. I'm overwhelmed by the amount of code you have presented and I guess you are too; try to cut the code down to the bare minimum to illustrate/test the issue. I always have a `prototype.py` file for testing small chunks out. Standard concepts don't need to be tested on your main code base, that makes things tough.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! I will try to do that with this and from now on. Sorry if i seem like a noob, I only just started coding like a months ago and only know a bit. But thank you for the tips ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR**

Don't have time to go through your code, but am guessing that you are getting the final results as a `list`, and so the

> cube volumes: []

The quick escape for this would be to use an `if` statement to check if the size of the list is `0`. ie, user did not give that `shape`.

So, a simple :

```
print('cube volumes:',end=' ')

#VolumeListCube is holding the final results
if len(VolumeListCube) == 0:
   print("You have not done any calculations for the cube")
else :
   #print your values as usual
```

should suffice.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help! This worked like a charm ^^
Sorry that my code is long and probably clustered like crazy, I only started coding at university a month ago, so only know a bit. But I am continuously trying to practice and get better, especially with organising the coding layout so it's more clean.
thank you so much for the help!

Comment: Sure, glad to help. A point of interest here. As seen in this case, the **long codes** are off putting and so most people will skip it. What you could have done is that instead of giving the full code, concentrate on smaller sections. And since all of them are similar, you just had to put the `cube` code. And since the problem is only in print area, just that, with a few lines of previous necessary `data storage` code would have been enough.

Comment: Thank you for the tips, I will definitely do that next time. Thank you again ^^